# Only getting a few markers in the map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am very new to angularJS and still exploring.I have created a map and showing around 1500 markers in it but when I load only 11 markers are visible.I am taking the Zip codes from a XML file and using geocoding I am converting them to LatLng and showing in map.Can any one suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
 //Angular App Module and Controller
var mapApp = angular.module('mapApp', []);

// app.directive("importSheetJs", [SheetJSImportDirective]);

mapApp.factory('mySHaredService', function ($rootScope) {
    var mySHaredService = {};
    mySHaredService.message = '';

    mySHaredService.prepForBroadcast = function (msg) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };
    return mySHaredService;
});

mapApp.controller('MapController', function ($scope, $timeout, $window, $rootScope, mySHaredService) {

    //Parsing data from XML
    $rootScope.zipArray = [];
    var url = "location.xlsx";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    $rootScope.LatLongList = [{
        "latitudeValue": "",
        "longitudeValue": ""
    }];
    oReq.onload = function (e) {
        var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
        var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        var bstr = arr.join("");

        var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });

        var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        var address_of_cell = "K1";
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
        data = JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));
        console.log("Messege data" + data);

        var finalData = JSON.parse(data);

        for (var i = 0; i <= finalData.length; i++) {
            // console.log("Zip code is " + finalData[i].Zip);
            $rootScope.zipArray.push(finalData[i].ZIP);
            console.log("Zip code inside zip array is " + $rootScope.zipArray[i]);

        }


    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {

        })

    }, 17770);

    $timeout(function() {

        console.log("Zip data from excel sheet" + $rootScope.zipArray)
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        for (var i = 15; i <= $rootScope.zipArray.length; i++) {
            var address = $rootScope.zipArray[i];
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    $rootScope.LatLongList.push({
                        "latitudeValue": latitude,
                        "longitudeValue": longitude
                    });

                }

            });

        }
        // setTimeout(function () {
        //     $scope.$apply(function () {

        //     })

        // }, 30000);

        $timeout(function () {

            console.log("Latitude value " + $rootScope.LatLongList[1].latitudeValue)


            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6496252, -117.9190418),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6496252, -117.9190418),
                map: $scope.map,
                radius: 10000,          // IN METERS.
                fillColor: '#FF6600',
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                strokeColor: "#FFF",
                strokeWeight: 0         // DON'T SHOW CIRCLE BORDER.
            });
            var bounds = circle.getBounds();

            $scope.markers = [];
            $rootScope.selectedAd = "";
            var selectedLocation = [{ "lat": 0, "long": 0 }];
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var createMarker = function (info) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitudeValue, info.longitudeValue),
                    title: ""
                });
                marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + '<br />' + info.latitudeValue + ' E,' + info.longitudeValue + ' N, </div>';

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' +
                        marker.content);
                    infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                    selectedLocation[0].lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                    selectedLocation[0].long = marker.getPosition().lng();
                    console.log("Latitude is " + selectedLocation[0].lat + "Longitude is " + selectedLocation[0].long);
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        latLng: marker.getPosition()
                    }, $scope.selectedLoc = function (responses) {
                        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                            // alert(responses[0].formatted_address);
                            $rootScope.selectedAd = responses[0].formatted_address;

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $scope.$apply(function () {
                                    $rootScope.selectedAd = responses[0].formatted_address;

                                })

                            }, 1000);

                            $timeout(function () {
                                $rootScope.selectedAd = responses[0].formatted_address;
                                $scope.handleClick = function (msg) {
                                    mySHaredService.prepForBroadcast($rootScope.selectedAd);
                                }
                                $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function () {
                                    $scope.message = $rootScope.selectedAd;
                                })

                            }, 2000);


                        } else {
                        }
                    });

                });
                $scope.markers.push(marker);

            }

            setTimeout(function () {

            }, 3000);

            $timeout(function () {
                for (i = 1; i < $rootScope.LatLongList.length; i++) {
                    console.log(bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng($rootScope.LatLongList[i].latitudeValue, $rootScope.LatLongList[i].longitudeValue)));
                    // if (bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng($rootScope.LatLongList[i].latitudeValue, $rootScope.LatLongList[i].longitudeValue))) {
                    createMarker($rootScope.LatLongList[i]);
                    console.log("The value of i is " + i);
                    // }

                }


            }, 4000);



            $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {

                var data = $rootScope.selectedAd
                this.broadcastItem();
                window.location = "valuePage.html";

            }

        }, 4000);


    }, 2000);


    oReq.send();



});

mapApp.controller("viewApp", function ($scope, $rootScope, mySHaredService, $timeout) {

    // $scope.selectedAd = Products.FirstName;
    // $scope.selectedAd = Products.FirstName;

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function () {
            $scope.message = mySHaredService.message;

        });

    }, 3000);

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function () {
            $scope.message = mySHaredService.message;

        });

    }, 4000);



});
```

Comment: Using only zip codes without any more additional address details is too ambiguous may not return a result. [Best Practices When Geocoding Addresses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices): "In general, use the Google Maps Geocoding API when geocoding complete addresses (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”). Use the Places API Place Autocomplete service when geocoding ambiguous (incomplete) addresses or for latency-sensitive applications, like when responding to user input."

Comment: Just found out that I am getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error in status of geocoding , is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43857218/5140781

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sending too many requests through per second.

> In addition to daily quota limits, the geocoding service is rate limited to 50 QPS (queries per second), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

The [Optimizing Quota Usage When Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies) has a lot of strategies on how to account for that.

In your case I suggest doing a randomized interval for each request you make that way they are spread out you avoid going over the 50 request per second limit.

I've modified the part of your code sample where you are making the request.

```
mapApp.controller('MapController', function ($scope, $timeout, $window, $rootScope, mySHaredService) {

//Parsing data from XML
$rootScope.zipArray = [];
var url = "location.xlsx";
var randomTime = Math.round(Math.random()*(3000-500))+500;    
var geocodeRequest = setTimeout(function() {
   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("GET", url, true);
   oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
   $rootScope.LatLongList = [{
      "latitudeValue": "",
      "longitudeValue": ""
   }];
   oReq.onload = function (e) {
     var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
     var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
     var arr = new Array();
     for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
     var bstr = arr.join("");

     var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });

     var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
     var address_of_cell = "K1";
     var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
     data = JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));
     console.log("Messege data" + data);

     var finalData = JSON.parse(data);

     for (var i = 0; i <= finalData.length; i++) {
        // console.log("Zip code is " + finalData[i].Zip);
        $rootScope.zipArray.push(finalData[i].ZIP);
        console.log("Zip code inside zip array is " + $rootScope.zipArray[i]);

     }


  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {

    })

  }, 17770);
}, randomTime);
```