# google geocoding OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-geocoder, geocoder

I know there are plenty of questions to this topics, but I couldn't find a proper explanation for my case. On my website the user manually clicks on the google map and then the geocode function is called. While "realistically" testing, nearly all calls takes more than 1 second to the next call (6 calls where around 0.9sec), see the logging of my geocode calls:

[image: log]
The 94th call hit the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

In total i had 424 geocoding calls today, see google metrics:

[image: geocoding metrics]

As far as I understand I'm far from the [usage limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#UsageLimits). (I am in the "Premium Plan"). So I don't understand why I'm exceeding the quota, any ideas? Or how high are the "initial quota of requests" and the "additional requests on a per-second basis"?

Comment: If you have a Premium plan license you should file support case directly with Google as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support. They will be able to investigate internal logs for you,

Comment: It looks like you might exceed the client side per session quota. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43857218/5140781 or you might send web service service side request without an API key and your quota is shared with over users. It's difficult to say without sample code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I contacted the google support - let's see what they say...